# Need to find sum square difference and the code is not producing the right answer, we have part of the code and had to fill in the blanks

Tags: c++

I have sample code and have to fill in the missing pieces. I've got the code working but the answer is not correct. The problem is to find the difference between the sum of the squares of the first ten natural numbers and the square of the sum.

The spots I have to fill in are:

- iostream in the brackets
- std after namespace
- sumsqr in the statement "int sumsqr = 1;"
- the initial number for int i in the for loop (I think this is where the problem is, not sure why "(N+1)" is used, but that is in the code we're given)
- the * in the statement sumsqr += i * i;
- sum, sum and sumsqr in the statement setting the value for solution
- solution in the cout statement

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int N = 10;
    int sum = 1;
    int sumsqr = 1;

    for (int i = 1; i < (N + 1); i++) {
        sum += i;
        sumsqr += i * i;
    }
    int solution = sum * sum - sumsqr;
    cout << solution;
    cin.get();
}
```

The answer should be, 2640, but I'm getting 2750.

Comment: Suggestion: rather than placing a console IO read at the end of the program to prevent the console window from closing when run in the IDE, place a debugger breakpoint at the end of the program

Comment: Speaking of breakpoints and debuggers, debuggers absolutely rule at helping find mistakes like this. You step through the program following the math until you see the program screw up the math. That't pretty much it. May take a while to change the logic so that it's correct, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're starting your sums at 1. The [empty sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empty_sum) is 0, not 1. Change this:

```
int sum = 1;
int sumsqr = 1;
```

to this:

```
int sum = 0;
int sumsqr = 0;
```

Alternatively, if you're not allowed to change that bit of the code for some reason, you can consider those numbers to be the sums of the first number. In that case, just start your loop at the second number, so change `int i = 1` to `int i = 2`.

Comment: I can't, that's part of the code I can't change.  I tried making int i = 0 and the answer stays the same.